# SharePoint 2007 control/webpart to display field value from another page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

In SharePoint 2007, how to display a value of a field from another page?

Similar to the below:

```
<SharePointWebControls:FieldValue id="PageTitle" FieldName="Title" runat="server"/>
```

but it's from another SharePoint page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePointWebControls:FieldValue displays values from the current SharePoint context, the current list item.

To display a value from another page, i suggest using the Content Query Web Part, to query the page you need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981241.aspx

Select the fields you want to display, the list you want to lookup, and item/page you want to select

```
<ViewFields>
 <FieldRef Name="Title" Nullable="True" Type="Text"/>
</ViewFields>
<Lists>
 <List ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}"/>
</Lists>
<Webs Recursive="True" />
<RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
<Where>
 <Gt>
  <FieldRef Name="Created" Nullable="True" Type="DateTime"/>
  <Value Type="DateTime"><Today OffsetDays="-7"/></Value>
 </Gt>
</Where>
```